# Windows Vista Network Folder and File Sharing

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking, windows-networking, wired-networking

I would like to know how to allow a user/username from a different computer (sample: \home-pc\Owner) to have viewing permissions and someone else (sample \home-pc\Guest) to have full accsess to the one folder (in this case, My documents).  How would I go about doing that via Windows Vista?  Oh, and by the way, I have tried this already but the computer name would not show up on my side at all.  My computer says that the computer could not be found.  I am on the same work group as the other computer is.

Answer (score 0):

Share the folder and create identical user credentials on each computer. Add the username to the shared folder permissions and your set. As a side note, if you do not have a DNS server you may have to map the hostnames to their appropriate IP address in the HOST file. Or simply use IP address's to access each machine.

ie: \\192.168.1.2\Share